# Scope of the array:

Tags: java, arrays

Here I am trying to find the max and min number entered into the array so I'm using a min and a max method(not declared yet) but I'm not quite sure how to access my array in these methods as the array userArray and array are not in the scope of the method and can't be accessed. can someone help me out?

```
package edu.skidmore.cs106.lab07.problem1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class numberArray {

//Method to take user input
    public int[] getUserData() {
        System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter?");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
        // Create variable to store user's desired number of values
        int totalNumbers = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        // Declare and initialze an array 
        int[] userArray = new int[totalNumbers];
        // Create a loop to ask for values from the user 
        // Within the loop, store user input in the array
        for (int x = 0; x < totalNumbers; ++x) { 
            System.out.println("Enter number " + x);
            int userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            userArray[x] = userInput;
        }
        return userArray;
    }
    public int minNumber() { 
        for (int y : array)
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        numberArray instance = new numberArray(); 
        int array[] = instance.getUserData(); 
        for (int element: array){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass arguments to methods.

Comment: Please note JavaScript _is not_ Java.

Comment: You could make the array an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int minNumber(int[] userDataArray) { 
    // use userDataArray here
}

...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    numberArray instance = new numberArray(); 
    int[] userDataArray = instance.getUserData(); 
    int min = instance.minNumber(userDataArray); // pass userDataArray as argument
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!